# Javascript syntax confusion [beginner]?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what view("") does in the following javascript method that is part of Model object:

```
addView: function(view) {
            this.views.push(view);
            view("");
        }
```

view(object) method is not defined anywhere...

Comment: What is the context? Where did you find this?

Comment: Then there is no use in using, remove `view("")` and see the difference.

Comment: hard to say. we dont see the whole code. view seems to be a function. it's not related to js.

Comment: Functions are objects. Read about "first class functions" in JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> view(object) method is not defined anywhere

The function that `view` is referring to is passed as **argument** to `addView`. This is also called a **callback**. A callback is a function (A) that is passed to another function (B) and is supposed to be called by that function (B).

So somewhere, there might be code that looks like

```
obj.addView(function(v) { 
   // using anonymous function expressions is a pretty common way to define
   // callbacks
});
```

or

```
function someFunctionName(v) {
    // any function will do, no matter how it is defined
}

obj.addView(someFunctionName);
```

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript and can be passed around like any other values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's passing in a function called view. Then it calls the view function.
Functions are first class citizens in JavaScript and can be passed as parameters to other functions.

```
addView: function(view) {//view is a function itself that is passed into the current function.
            this.views.push(view);
            view("");
        }
```

The call could be like this

```
someObj.addView(function(par1){alert("I am a function too")});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have function `view` , if you call the `view` function without passing parameter in   `view()`, then it returns like `undefined`, In such case we need to initialise the passing parameter value from function `view("")`

```
function view(passedData){

   alert (passedData);
}
```